# the barStyle="dark-content" of the statusBar does not work on android 5

Tags: react-native

The `barStyle="dark-content"` of the statusBar does not work on Android 5, but it can work on Android 6 well.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ScrollView, View, Text, Navigator, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class FixedDimensionsBasics extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor={"blue"} barStyle={'dark-content'} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn_practice', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

My mobile phone device run result (红米 Note 3/ Android 5.1.1 LMY47V)

[image: StatusBar not dark]

on android emulator (Nexus 6/ Android 6)

[image: StatusBar dark]

how to make it work on android 5?

Answer (score -1):

regarding to documenation: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

barStyle is iOS only prop so there is no possibility to change status bar on android with this method.

You can use backgroundColor for android :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I want to know how to make the status bar icon and font becomes black, because other APP can change the icon and font color on android 5, I'm not sure it use react-native to develop or  java.